# Auto-mapper issue

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to test out my requests in Postman and I get an error about mapping.

Movie model

```
public class Movie : BaseEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
```

Rental model

```
public class Rental : BaseEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int MovieId { get; set; }

        public decimal DateRented { get; set; }

        public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }
    }
```

Mapper.cs

```
 public class MapperProfile : Profile
    {
        public MapperProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Movie, MovieDTO>().ReverseMap();
            CreateMap<Rental, RentalDTO>().ReverseMap();
        }
    }
```

The Postman error

`AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.`

Edit to add DTO classes.
MovieDTO

```
public class MovieDTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
```

RentalDTO

```
public class RentalDTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int MovieId { get; set; }

        public decimal DateRented { get; set; }

        public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm not sure if it is correct, but it has all the same info as the regular model classes.

Edit 2:

Startup

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddOptions();
            services.AddDataServices(Configuration);
            services.AddProviders();
            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MapperProfile));

            services.AddControllers(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(new HttpResponseExceptionFilter());
            })
                .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context =>
                    {
                        var result = new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
                        result.ContentTypes.Add(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json);
                        result.ContentTypes.Add(MediaTypeNames.Application.Xml);
                        return result;
                    };
                });
}
```

I'm wondering if it has to do with my need for the rentalId and movieId in the controller route as well.

For instance: Movie Controller

```
[Route("/rentals/{rentalId}/movies")]
    public class MoviesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<MoviesController> _logger;
        private readonly IMovieProvider _movieProvider;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public MoviesController(
            ILogger<MoviesController> logger,
            IMovieProvider movieProvider,
            IMapper mapper)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _mapper = mapper;
            _movieProvider = movieProvider;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<MovieDTO>>> GetMovieByRentalIdAsync(string rentalId)
        {
            int rentalIdInput;

            try
            {
                rentalIdInput = Convert.ToInt32(rentalId);
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                throw new NotFoundException($"Movie with Id: {rentalId} does not exist in the database");
            }

            var movie = await _movieProvider.GetMovieByRentalIdAsync(rentalIdInput);
            var movieDTO = _mapper.Map<MovieDTO>(movie); <--------- this line also shows up on the Postman error : "Mapping types: Object -> MovieDTO System.Object -> Movies.MovieDTO at lambda_method401(Closure , Object , MovieDTO , ResolutionContext )"

            return Ok(movieDTO);
        }
   }
```

Comment: can we see the `MovieDTO` and `RentalDTO`?

Comment: @BagusTesa I have added them

Comment: try remove the `ReverseMap()` and see if it works. it is possible if you write `CustomerName` the AutoMapper (with `ReverseMap()` set) will expect an instance of `Customer` with property called `Name`.

Comment: still didn't work for me

Comment: you are right, `CustomerName` isnt the problem. i've tested on dotnet fiddle and it works either way. how did you use the mapper? manually via `MapperConfiguration` instance? or dependency injection? if its the former, you need to register the profile to `MapperConfiguration` first then use that config instance to create mapper . if its the later, rajesh is right - you need to chug in the service registration. that error appears as if your `MapperProfile` is not properly registered to the config instance.

Comment: @BagusTesa I have added ,more context into what I am trying to accomplish as well as more error details.

Answer (score -2):

```
namespace AutoMapperDemo {
    public class Startup {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which file should I put it in?

Comment: Check this Configuration was added in Startup Class

Comment: Yes, I do have this.

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to add explaination of your code ?